# corporate proxy blocks plugins.gradle.org

Tags: gradle, quarkus

I am trying to get a sample quarkus gradle project to run on my corporate laptop. And unfortunately plugins.gradle.org is blocked.

So I manually downloaded the two plugin dependencies and set it up in my local c:/m2/repo

The POM which include the plug in jar

```
<groupId>io.quarkus<groupId>
<artifactId>io.quarkus.gradle.plugin<artifactId>
<version>1.9.2.Final<version>
location : plugins.gradle.org/m2/io/quarkus/io.quarkus.gradle.plugin/1.9.2.Final
```

and the plug-in jar

```
<groupId>gradle.plugin.io.quarkus<groupId>
<artifactId>quarkus-gradle-plugin<artifactId>
<version>1.9.2.Final<version>
location: plugins.gradle.org/m2/gradle/plugin/io/quarkus/quarkus-gradle-plugin/1.9.2.Final
```

And I am getting the following error

```
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)

- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'io.quarkus:io.quarkus.gradle.plugin:1.9.2.Final')

  Searched in the following repositories:

    MavenLocal(file:/C:/m2/repo/)
```

I noticed there are a lot of posts aroung org.gradle namespace, but none of them had proper answers.

Thanks for the help!